# JW Player Android Not able to Play DRM Content

Tags: android, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I have used sample JWPlayer github example to test the normal content.
The normal content played well.
When I tested the DRM Content. It didn't Played.
I also followed the documentation.
Following is the link
https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/drm/drm-protected-playback/
I was bit confused with the values to be provided to videoId and provider in the given url.